# How this c program is evaluating

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define dprintf(expr) printf(#expr "=%d\n",expr)

int main()
{
    int x=7;
    int y=3;
    dprintf(x/y);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting output as x/y=2 
I am confused how "x/y" is getting printed

Comment: What you expect from `printf("x/y" "=%d\n",x/y);` ?

Comment: That's what the `#` stringizing operator (which works only in macro definitions) does. Consult any C decent reference for more information. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace (scroll down to **# and ## operators**).

Comment: its #expr how is it evaluating to "x/y" it should be #x/y

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx

Comment: If you want `#x/y` to be printed you need `printf("#" #expr "=%d\n", expr)`

Comment: [ISO/IEC 9998/1999](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring13/CSCI-GA.2110-001/downloads/C99.pdf)$6.10.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a macro the `#` [stringifies](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) the operands so `#expr` will take the arguments and turn them into a string and since adjacent string literals are concatenated it will be then be concatenated to `"=%d\n"` so you end up with:

```
printf( "x/y" "=%d\n",expr)
```

which will become:

```
printf( "x/y=%d\n",expr)
```

For complete sake from the draft [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.10.3.2` *The # operator* paragraph *2* covers the `#` it is rather long and hard to read so I won't quote it but section `5.1.1.2` *Translation phases* paragraph *6* says:

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated

Answer (score 1):

```
dprintf(x/y);
```

expands to

```
printf("x/y" "=%d\n", x/y);
```

which is evaluated as:

```
printf("x/y" "=%d\n", 7 / 3);
```

now since x and y are integers, the result of x/y is 2 (an integer)

so the output is `x/y=2`

Note the c preprocessor # directive replaces #expr with "expr".

Note also the c compiler will simply concatenate adjacent string literals into one string, i.e. `printf("Hello " "World\n");` is equivalent to `printf("Hello World\n");`

see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification for more details.